# optimizing project euler #83 solution

Tags: python, optimization, algorithm, project-euler

[Project Euler problem 83](http://projecteuler.net/problem=83) asks:

> In the 5 by 5 matrix below,
>
> ```
> 131   673 234 103 18
> 201   96  342 965 150
> 630   803 746 422 111
> 537   699 497 121 956
> 805   732 524 37  331
> ```
>
> the minimal path sum from the top left to the bottom right, by moving left, right, up, and down, is
>
> ```
> 131 → 201 → 96 → 342 → 234 → 103 → 18 → 150 → 111 → 422 → 121 → 37 → 331
> ```
>
> and is equal to 2297.
>
> Find the minimal path sum, in [`matrix.txt`](http://projecteuler.net/project/matrix.txt) (right click and 'Save
>   Link/Target As...'), a 31K text file containing a 80 by 80 matrix,
>   from the top left to the bottom right by only moving right and down.

I have solved the project euler problem 83 using uniform cost search. This solution takes about 0.6s to solve. I want to know if anyone can get the code to run relatively faster without changing the general outline of the program.

```
import bisect
f = open('matrix.txt')
matrix = [[int(i) for i in j.split(',')] for j in f]

def uniformCostSearch(startNode):
    frontier = []
    frontier.append(startNode)
    closedSet = set()
    while not len(frontier) == 0:
        currentNode = frontier.pop(0)
        if currentNode.x == 79 and currentNode.y == 79:
            return currentNode.priority
        else:
            if not (currentNode.x, currentNode.y) in closedSet:
                closedSet.add((currentNode.x, currentNode.y))
        possibleMoves = currentNode.neighbors()
        for move in possibleMoves:
            if not (move.x, move.y) in closedSet:
                try:
                    index = frontier.index(move)
                    if move.priority < frontier[index].priority:
                        frontier.pop(index)
                        bisect.insort_left(frontier, move)
                except ValueError:
                    # move is not in frontier so just add it
                    bisect.insort_left(frontier, move)
    return -1


class Node:
    def __init__(self, x, y, priority=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.priority = priority

    def neighbors(self):
        tmp = [Node(self.x + 1, self.y), Node(self.x, self.y + 1),
               Node(self.x - 1, self.y), Node(self.x, self.y - 1),]
        childNodes = []
        for node in tmp:
            if node.x >= 0 and node.y >= 0 and node.x <= 79 and node.y <= 79:
                node.priority = self.priority + matrix[node.y][node.x]
                childNodes.append(node)
        return childNodes

    def __eq__(self, node):
        return self.x == node.x and self.y == node.y

    def __ne__(self, node):
        return not self.x == node.x and self.y == node.y

    def __cmp__(self, node):
        if self.priority < node.priority:
            return -1
        elif self.priority > node.priority:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: Why not use a classical Dijkstra?

Comment: I turned the matrix into a graph and used a shortest path algorithm for this problem which got me the solution in 0.069s. I'll take a look through yours though and see if I can optimize it in anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
import bisect
f = open('matrix.txt')
matrix = [[int(i) for i in j.split(',')] for j in f]
```

You could consider using the numpy library, it'll handle multidimensional arrays more neatly and efficiently.

```
def uniformCostSearch(startNode):
```

Python convention is to use underscore_with_letters for function names and parameters

```
    frontier = []
    frontier.append(startNode)
```

Use `frontier = [startNode]`, it'll be a touch faster

```
    closedSet = set()
    while not len(frontier) == 0:
```

Use `while frontier:`, it does the same thing and due to less operations is going to be a bit faster. You should at least use `!=` rather then `not ==`

```
        currentNode = frontier.pop(0)
```

Popping from the front of a list will be inefficient. Actually, what you really want is a priority queue, see python's deque module.

```
        if currentNode.x == 79 and currentNode.y == 79:
            return currentNode.priority
        else:
            if not (currentNode.x, currentNode.y) in closedSet:
```

Move the `not` over next to `in` I think it reads clearer. I might also use a 2D array of bools rather then a set here.

```
                closedSet.add((currentNode.x, currentNode.y))
```

There isn't really any reason to check if the node is in the set here, you can add the node multiple times. Just add it unconditionally.

```
        possibleMoves = currentNode.neighbors()
        for move in possibleMoves:
```

No reason to store it in a local, just combine the previous two lines

```
            if not (move.x, move.y) in closedSet:
                try:
                    index = frontier.index(move)
                    if move.priority < frontier[index].priority:
                        frontier.pop(index)
                        bisect.insort_left(frontier, move)
```

Move the last three lines into an else block. That'll make sure only your index line can actually throw things that'll get caught.

```
                except ValueError:
                    # move is not in frontier so just add it
                    bisect.insort_left(frontier, move)
```

You do this in either case, I'd move it after the try/except block.
        return -1

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x, y, priority=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.priority = priority

    def neighbors(self):
        tmp = [Node(self.x + 1, self.y), Node(self.x, self.y + 1),
               Node(self.x - 1, self.y), Node(self.x, self.y - 1),]
        childNodes = []
        for node in tmp:
            if node.x >= 0 and node.y >= 0 and node.x <= 79 and node.y <= 79:
```

I suggest moving 79 into a constant. I'd also do `< 80` rather then `<= 79`.

```
                node.priority = self.priority + matrix[node.y][node.x]
                childNodes.append(node)
```

I'd use a yield here, and make this a generator

```
        return childNodes

    def __eq__(self, node):
        return self.x == node.x and self.y == node.y
```

This bothers me because multiple nodes will compare equal despite having different priorities.

```
    def __ne__(self, node):
        return not self.x == node.x and self.y == node.y

    def __cmp__(self, node):
        if self.priority < node.priority:
            return -1
        elif self.priority > node.priority:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

This really bothers me because you aren't defining your comparisons in a consistent way.